# Are there different libraries of Windows system calls?

Tags: windows, kernel, system-calls, trace

From looking at traces of system calls in Windows, I am very confused by the different types of these. Here are some different types I've encountered:

```
NtQueryPerformanceCounter( Counter=0xbcf6c8 [1.45779e+009], Freq=null ) => 0
NtProtectVirtualMemory( ProcessHandle=-1, BaseAddress=0xbcf6f4 …
NtProtectVirtualMemory( ProcessHandle=-1, BaseAddress=0xbcf6f4 [0x7702e000]…
NtQuerySystemInformation( SystemInformationClass=0 [SystemBasicInformation]
NtQueryVirtualMemory( ProcessHandle=-1, BaseAddress=0x76f20000, MemoryInformationClass=6, MemoryInformation=0xbcf440, Length=0xc, ReturnLength=null ) => 0
```

I know that these are referred to as API system calls. My untrained eye classify these as system calls that start with "Nt".

But I've also encountered these:

```
"CreateSemaphoreW","CreateSemaphoreA","GlobalAddAtomW","lstrcpynW","LoadLibraryExW","SearchPathW",
"CreateFileW","CreateFileMappingW","MapViewOfFileEx","GetSystemMetrics","RegisterClipboardFormatW","SystemParametersInfoW",
"GetDC","GetDeviceCaps","ReleaseDC","LocalAlloc"
```

Although I may be wrong, I assume that these are system calls that are lower in level than those that start with Nt.

And this is another trace that I've encountered:

```
  HeapAlloc HeapAlloc HeapFree HeapFree HeapAlloc HeapAlloc HeapFree 
HeapFree NtOpenKey GetProcessHeap HeapAlloc NtOpenKey HeapAlloc NtOpenKey
 NtQueryValueKey NtQueryValueKey HeapFree HeapAlloc HeapAlloc NtOpenKey 
NtQueryValueKey HeapAlloc HeapAlloc RegOpenKeyExW
```

This trace contains both Nt and those without... I understand that I may sound too unknowledgeable in this field but I really would like to develop a better general idea of what these are.

These traces make me assume that there are different sets of system calls that people seem to refer to them in the same name ("system calls"), in Windows. Could somebody tell me if I am wrong? And if I am right, are there names for these different sets of system calls?

Thank you

Comment: Windows (NT) system calls are generally prefixed with `Nt` (ntdll.dll) or `NtUser` or `NtGdi` (win32u.dll in Windows 10). These are stub functions that pass the function number in the [system call table](http://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64) to a kernel mode dispatcher (e.g. via the x64 `sysenter` or `syscall` instructions). You may also see `Zw` prefixed names. From user mode these are the same as the `Nt` function names. They're different in the kernel, but that's not directly related to your question.

Comment: Others such as `CreateFileW` and `HeapAlloc` are Windows API calls. Usually these perform as much work and preparation as possible in user mode -- often via runtime library functions such as `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U` and `RtlAllocateHeap` (in ntdll.dll). Ultimately they call (or may call) a kernel system function such as `NtCreateFile` or `NtAllocateVirtualMemory`.

Comment: There are also calls such as `CreateProcessWithLogonW` that are implemented by making an RPC call to a system service (e.g. the Secondary Logon service in this case). If it's over an LPC port, then the system call might be `NtAlpcSendWaitReceivePort`. The service is often privileged to make other calls such  as `CreateProcessAsUser`, which ultimately calls `NtCreateUserProcess`.

Comment: In case anyone else is curious, I believe the questioner is using the '[NtTrace](http://rogerorr.github.io/NtTrace/)' utility by Roger Orr.

Answer (score 2):

The top snippet shows native api function names, the actual api of the operating system.  The api you'd target when you write drivers.  But that is rarely the api you use when you write your own programs.  Windows NT originally included three distinct api layers, Win32, OS/2 and Posix.

The second snippet shows function names from the Win32 api layer, by far the most common one you target when you write a Windows program.  The OS/2 subsystem was retired a long time ago.  Posix fell out of use and was discontinued at Win8 and Server2012, but is back in Win10 with the new Linux subsystem.

Such a subsystem is implemented by translating its api functions into equivalent native api functions, if any.  Most of the Win32 subsystem code lives in kernel32.dll, gdi32.dll, user32.dll and advapi.dll.  ntdll.dll is the native api wrapper that calls into the kernel when necessary.  Native api function names start with Nt or Zw.  There is a glue layer that marries the two that gets exposed occasionally, its function names start with Rtl.

Primary advantage of this layering is that Microsoft can innovate on the OS without breaking existing programs.  Code that was written 30 years ago is still pretty likely to compile and run correctly on a current OS, in spite of two very drastic architecture changes and many Windows releases.  The last big change to the native api was at Vista, major version 6.

Comment: The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) is not a traditional NT subsystem, unlike the previous POSIX and OS/2 subsystems. It doesn't require building PE binaries from source. Instead it uses pico processes with existing Linux ELF binaries.

Comment: What does it mean to "target" an api layer?

Comment: Write a program that uses the specific apis.